# In C#, what is the right way to post attachments to Confluence REST API?

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am migrating from Confluence's SOAP API to using [their REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest).  I see there is support [for adding attachments to a page (by doing a POST)](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/#d3e787) but I am running into issues getting it to work (I am getting a **403: Forbidden** Error message).  I have other "get" items working fine through the rest api but doing an attachment post seems to keep failing.

Here is my current code (given a specific filename):

```
 byte[] rawData = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
 var pageId = "11134";
 var url = new Uri("http://example.com:9088/rest/api/content/" + pageId + "/child/attachment");
 var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
 var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(rawData);
 imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(attachement.contentType);
 requestContent.Add(imageContent, "file", attachement.fileName);
 requestContent.Headers.Add("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
```

Can you see if I am doing anything wrong above?

Comment: Confluence docs stays: "Returned if attachments is disabled or if you don't have permission to add attachments to this content.". Have you tried using CURL like in the page here https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/#d3e787 and see if it still returns 403?

Comment: I just tried curl and I get an error curl <56> Recv  failure: Connection was reset.  I used this syntax            curl -D- -u user:pwd -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@test.txt" htttp://example:9088/rest/api/content/71105117/child/attachment  (NOTE: I put an extra "t" in "http" in this comment so SO wouldn't try to convert it to a hyperlink

Comment: @SimonMourier - also, is there other authentication required on the C# code above?

Comment: Oh, yes, probably you need to add some credentials to the request.

Comment: Have you checked the settings of Confluence? Are Attachments allowed in Confluence? System-> Select Advanced -> Attachments

Comment: @Jehof. Yes as per my question. The SOAP equivalent of the above code worked fine

Comment: Their documentation says that you receive a 403 error: `Returned if attachments is disabled or if you don't have permission to add attachments to this content.` - Did you see that?

Comment: i see in your code attachement.contentType & attachement.fileName where is the declaration of that variable ?

Answer (score 5):

403 status indicates that request is not authorized. In order to authorize a request you need to specify `Authorization` header. Confluence REST API supports Basic authorization scheme. For basic authentication you need to specify the following header with each request: `Authorization: Basic username:password` where *username:password* part should be Base64-encoded. You can use the following code in order to do this:

```
string userName;
string password;
string authorizationString = userName + ":" + password;
string encodedValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authorizationString));
string authorizationHeaderValue = "Basic " + encodedValue;

requestContent.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeaderValue);
```

According to this [link](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/confluence-rest-apis-prototype-only/using-the-rest-apis-prototype-only) you also should specify the following url parameter with each request: `os_authType=basic`.

> HTTP basic authentication: (Authorization HTTP header) containing
>   'Basic username:password'. Please note however, username:password must
>   be base64 encoded. The URL must also contain the **'os_authType=basic'**
>   query parameter.

Note: make sure to connect via https if using basic authentication;

Answer (score 3):

From Confluence documentation (RTFM)

> In order to protect against XSRF attacks, because this method accepts multipart/form-data, it has XSRF protection on it. This means you must submit a header of X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck with the request, otherwise it will be blocked.

Add this before the `Post`

```
httpClient.Headers.Add("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
```

Comment: I have added the new line and updated the question.  The issue now is that tried adding this and now I get 403: Forbidden

Comment: SO stipulates only 1 question per post.  Changing to a new question should be another post.  The reason for this is for other people to be able to search for answers to a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I prefer:

```
string url = "https://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/123456/child/attachment";
string filename = @"C:\temp\test.txt";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string authorizationString = username + ":" + password;
    string encodedValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authorizationString));
    client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedValue);
    client.Headers.Add("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
    byte[] result = client.UploadFile(url, filename);
    string responseAsString = Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
}
```